# want to prevent drop down menu being open by default

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the mobile view (window size less than 800px), the dropdown menu is open by default now and covers up the content. I want the menu to be hidden until the toggle button is clicked.

the website : jweeklyusa.com

To be honest, I can write html and css but I don't really know much about javascript. I really appreciate it if you can help me. Thank you.

```js
/* Add Menu Toggle Button for mobile navigation */
$("#main-navigation").before('<button id=\"main-navigation-toggle\" class=\"main-navigation-toggle\"></button>');

/* Add dropdown slide animation for mobile devices */
$('#main-navigation-toggle').on('click', function(){
  menu_wrap.slideToggle();
  $( this ).toggleClass('active');
});

/* Add submenus for mobile navigation menu */
main_menu.addMobileSubmenu();
header_menu.addMobileSubmenu();

} );
```

```html
<nav id="main-navigation" class="primary-navigation navigation clearfix" role="navigation">
<div class="main-navigation-menu-wrap">

  <?php
    // Display Main Navigation.
    wp_nav_menu( array(
      'theme_location' => 'primary',
      'container' => false,
      'menu_class' => 'main-navigation-menu',
      'echo' => true,
      'fallback_cb' => 'admiral_default_menu',
      )
    );
  ?>
</div><!-- main-navigation-menu-wrap -->
</nav><!-- #main-navigation -->
```

Comment: edit style.css like this .main-navigation-menu-wrap {
    display: none;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 0px solid #ffffff;
     flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Chrome inspector, it seems that there are 2 display element in your CSS for this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 720px)
.main-navigation-menu-wrap

    display: none;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 0px solid #ffffff;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
```

Try remove the `display: flex;` line and see if it's fixed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you very much :D (and now I remember how it got there...)

Answer (score 1):

In the jQuery documentation for slideToggle(), it says "If the element is initially displayed, it will be hidden; if hidden, it will be shown."

It looks like you initially have the CSS display set to "none."  Try removing that property initially.

Comment: the other answer solved the problem but thank you for the quick reply!